# Laptop bluetooth driver/adapter works in ubuntu but not in windows 7/8

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, windows-8, wireless-networking, bluetooth

I have acer 4253 laptop with amd e350 processor and 2GB RAM attaced. Initially the bluetooth worked well with windows 7. Later I turned off the adapter using the preinstalled OEM software 'Bluetooth Suite' by atheros.  Then accidentally i deleted the bluetooth suite software. The bluetooth adapter was not even detected in hardware device manager. When i reinstalled the bluetooth suite, i shows as if i have no bluetooth adapters. At first i thought that my adapter was damaged somehow. I realized that this was untrue when i first installed ubuntu 11. The bluetooth adapter was detected in linux and worked seamlessly.. Later I purchase windows 8 and did a fresh install. The bluetooth adapter was still not visible. Later I dual booted with ubuntu 12 and fedora 17 . The bluetooth appeared in both linux distros but not windows 8. Is there a way i could bring my bluetooth back to win 8?

Laptop config ::
Acer 4253
2GB RAM
AMD E-350 Processor
500 GB HDD

installed os : Windows 8, ubuntu 12.10 and fedora 17
ps :No problems with wifi adapter till now.

Answer (score 2):

If you are able to see the "Bluetooth Radio" icon in the "Right click on My computer -> Properties -> Device Manager on the top left" then click on Bluetooth Radio -> properties -> select the tab of Power Management and un-check the box for "Turn off device to save power". Now Restart your computer and check the outcome.

Or,

I would recommend you to download the Bluetooth driver from the vendor site and run it in your machine to detect the adapter. Please ensure that you have deleted/Uninstalled the existing bluetooth drivers if any.

Also, check the BIOS settings of the Bluetooth option and ensure it is enabled.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The bluetooth radio icon doesnt appear any more. I downloaded and reinstalled the bluetooth suite software but it is of no use.

Answer (score 0):

Try holding <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> for 3-4 seconds.